# How to dynamically switch code splitting on/off

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, import, code-splitting

We have a ReactJS app that we bundle with webpack.
We use React-Loadable to help us with code splitting and right now our app's router module looks like

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable'

const LoadableComponent = (url, component)=>Loadable({
    loader:()=> import(`${url}`),
    loading: ()=><div></div>,
    render(loaded, props){
        let LoadedComponent = loaded[component]
        return <LoadedComponent {...props}/>
    }
})

const Landing = LoadableComponent('./components/LandingPage', 'Landing')
// ... all the other imports have this form ^
```

That being said, during development, code splitting seems to slow down `webpack --watch` and can make debugging in browser be a bit more of a pain (we don't use sourcemaps because they haven't worked great for us in the past).

I'm trying to figure out a way to dynamically switch code-splitting on or off. My idea is to make `LoadableComponent` act like a normal import when code-splitting is off. However, both `import` and `react-loadable` seem a bit too mystical for it to be straightforward, I haven't been able to find a way to do that in javascript.

Comment: If you can upgrade to `v16.6.0`, you can try [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html#reactlazy-code-splitting-with-suspense) (just released this week). I am not sure if it'd fix the performance issue though but wouldn't hurt to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could try and this will depend on your webpack implementation but if you have a development webpack.config ie `webpack.config.dev.js` you could add to the plugins array:

```
new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
  maxChunks: 1
})
```

This will stop the code splitting and only builds one file. In my tests so far `react-loadable` seems to be cool with this and just work as per normal with out the code splitting.

If you wanted a way to switch this on and off dynamically you could pass a command line argument to webpack when you start it up and then conditionally add the above code. At the bottom of your webpack config file.

```
if (yourArgHere) {
  module.exports.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1
    })
  );
}
```